# NullPointerException when using AutoCompleteTextView android

Tags: android

The exception

```
09-09 23:55:25.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14983): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 23:55:25.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14983):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:353)
09-09 23:55:25.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14983):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
09-09 23:55:25.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14983):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
09-09 23:55:25.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14983):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownListView.obtainView(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1656)
09-09 23:55:25.336: E/AndroidRuntime(14983):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1264)
```

The code

```
    fromAutoComplete = new AutoComplete(
            this, // R.layout.fromautocomplete,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
            R.id.fromautocomplete);
    fromAutoComplete.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    fromAddress = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.fromAddress);
    fromAddress.setAdapter(fromAutoComplete);
    fromAddress.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    fromAddress.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    fromAddress.setOnClickListener(this);
    toAutoComplete = new AutoComplete(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
            // R.layout.toautocomplete,
            R.id.toautocomplete);
    toAutoComplete.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    toAddress = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.toAddress);
    toAddress.setAdapter(toAutoComplete);
    toAddress.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    toAddress.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    toAddress.setOnClickListener(this);
```

The AutoComplete (some relevant lines of code)

```
public class AutoComplete extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

public AutoComplete(Activity activity, int layout, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(activity, layout, textViewResourceId);
    //super(activity, textViewResourceId);  
}
```

Results

1. toaddress works fine,
2. fromaddress crash's

Obviously this is a autocomplete thing, so its not crashing in the code, but in the inflation

**Edit : fixed the issue by**

```
    toAutoComplete = new AutoComplete(this,            
        R.layout.toautocomplete,
        R.id.toautocomplete);
    fromAutoComplete = new AutoComplete(
            this, R.layout.fromautocomplete,
            R.id.fromautocomplete);
```

Comment: the textview id you refer is not present in the layout you use. hence the crash

Comment: thanks, worked nicely

Answer (score 0):

Edit : fixed the issue by

```
toAutoComplete = new AutoComplete(this,            
    R.layout.toautocomplete,
    R.id.toautocomplete);
fromAutoComplete = new AutoComplete(
        this, R.layout.fromautocomplete,
        R.id.fromautocomplete);
```